# Turning a .jui file into a .java file, qt-jamba

Tags: java, qt-designer, qt-jambi

I use this method (found on another question) to turn my .ui file into a .jui file.

1.Open the .ui file using a text editor (I used gedit)

2.Remove the first line of the file which looks something like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

3.Delete the whitespace on the top of the file.

4.Modify this line of code : `<ui version="4.0"> to look like this <ui version="4.0" language="jambi"> This line should be at the top of the file.`

5.Modify the file extension to be .jui

after this, im stuck on how to turn my .jui file into a .java file, or simply run the file from another .java file (i use eclipse), and reference the objects (like textfields and buttons) that are in my .jui file.

Does anyone know of a tutorial showing how to do this? I cannot find one. Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Having never used qt, or what I am guessing is qt-jambi, but I found this short tutorial that might help: http://ooboontoo.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-basics-using-qt-jambi-tutorial_25.html

Comment: wow dude, thanks a ton it worked. Just goes to show google searching is the only real skill in this world :P:P:P Please put this in an actual answer so I can checkmark it and give you credit. I coppied my .jui file into the folder with the juic.exe and then ran it from command line!!! thanks!

Comment: No Problem, just glad I could help. As a note, I would be close to useless with out google.

Comment: now I just need to figure out how to run the java code it generated lol.

Comment: You could ask another question and post the code it generated. Other may be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have no real experience with qt-designer or qt-jambi for that matter, there is a short tutorial I found [here](http://ooboontoo.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-basics-using-qt-jambi-tutorial_25.html) that seems to have some useful information. Based on the OP's comment all he had to do was copy the .jui file into the folder with the juic.exe and then run it from command line.